# Does swift actors have its own executors?

Tags: swift, async-await, concurrency, actor

I'm looking at sources of actor. And can't determine does swift actor creates it's own executor on initialization step.
Example from swiftrocks:

```
actor MyActor {}

// Compiled:

final class MyActor: Actor {
    var unownedExecutor: UnownedSerialExecutor {
        return Builtin.buildDefaultActorExecutorRef(self) // We are building executor passing self, so seems that it's bound to object, not to type
    }

    init() {
        _defaultActorInitialize(self)
    }

    deinit {
        _defaultActorDestroy(self)
    }
}
```

So does each instance of actor have it's own executor and run in parallel with other instance of the same actor type. Or they share executor?

I think that would be strange to use shared executor, but want to be sure, is my understanding correct.

Answer (score 1):

I would separate 2 things:

- Whether or not actors may share the same executor (it may be not a single instance, but for example a limited executor pool).
- Whether or not each instance of actor will run in parallel with other instance of the same actor type, regardless of how their executor is implemented. This part can be proven with this simple test:

```
actor A {
    
    let name: String
    
    init(_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    
    func doSomething() {
        print("\(name) started \(Date())")
        sleep(UInt32.random(in: 1...3))
        print("\(name) finished \(Date())")
    }
}
```

Now lets create an instance of it:

```
let a1 = A("a1")
```

And run it on multiple threads like this:

```
DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 20) { i in
    Task.detached(priority: .userInitiated) {
        a1.doSomething()
    }
}
```

Predictably we will get a sequence of executions:

```
a1 started 2022-07-03 16:42:22 +0000 on thread: <NSThread: 0x6000018d8080>{number = 8, name = (null)}
a1 finished 2022-07-03 16:42:23 +0000
a1 started 2022-07-03 16:42:23 +0000 on thread: <NSThread: 0x6000018f1c40>{number = 10, name = (null)}
a1 finished 2022-07-03 16:42:25 +0000
...
```

Now lets try to have 3 instances of the same actor:

```
let a1 = A("a1")
let a2 = A("a2")
let a3 = A("a3")
```

and run them the same way:

```
DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 20) { i in
    
    Task.detached(priority: .userInitiated) {
        switch i%3 {
        case 0:
            await a1.doSomething()
        case 1:
            await a2.doSomething()
        case 2:
            await a3.doSomething()
        default:
            await a1.doSomething()
```

So now you will see:

```
a2 started 2022-07-03 16:43:40 +0000 on thread: <NSThread: 0x60000229db80>{number = 10, name = (null)}
a3 started 2022-07-03 16:43:40 +0000 on thread: <NSThread: 0x600002290e80>{number = 9, name = (null)}
a2 finished 2022-07-03 16:43:41 +0000
a1 started 2022-07-03 16:43:41 +0000 on thread: <NSThread: 0x60000229db80>{number = 10, name = (null)}
a3 finished 2022-07-03 16:43:43 +0000
a2 started 2022-07-03 16:43:43 +0000 on thread: <NSThread: 0x600002290e80>{number = 9, name = (null)}
a1 finished 2022-07-03 16:43:44 +0000
a3 started 2022-07-03 16:43:44 +0000 on thread: <NSThread: 0x60000229db80>{number = 10, name = (null)}
a2 finished 2022-07-03 16:43:44 +0000
a1 started 2022-07-03 16:43:44 +0000 on thread: <NSThread: 0x600002290e80>{number = 9, name = (null)}
a3 finished 2022-07-03 16:43:45 +0000
a2 started 2022-07-03 16:43:45 +0000 on thread: <NSThread: 0x6000022a25c0>{number = 11, name = (null)}
a1 finished 2022-07-03 16:43:45 +0000
...
```

So that proves that **each instance of actor will run in parallel with other instance of the same actor type**. Practically this is all you need to know.

Now to the first question: it's clear that since 2 or more actor instances can be executed concurrently on sequential executor, there has to be more than one executor. But it also doesn't proof that each actor instance has its own executor: there may be a limited pool of executors, from which actor instance get their executor instance... This is something very hard to prove - would be easier to inspect the source code. Even the docs can be read both ways, for example in `UnownedSerialExecutor` the docs say:

> For example, keeping an actor alive must also keep the actor’s associated executor alive; if they are different objects, the executor must be referenced strongly by the actor.

(i.e. what do they mean by "associated"? the one created specifically for the actor, or the one assigned to this actor from the pool?)

So this is the question, which I think can only be answered by Apple folks. Would be interesting to know the answer though.

Comment: @jiquirckart yo, thanks for the answer, really appreciate it.
But I think your example doesn't prove that it is parallel execution. Look at the seconds on your output. When blocking IO ends, immediately new subtask starts, but when it's blocked nothing is starting.

Comment: Check this, it's serial:
actor SomeActor {
    let name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    func run() {
        print("Started actor: \(name)")
        sleep(3)
        print("Ended actor: \(name)")
    }
}
let act1 = SomeActor(name: "A")
let act2 = SomeActor(name: "B")
DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 20) { i in
    Task.detached(priority: .userInitiated) {
        switch i%2 {
        case 0:
            await act1.run()
        case 1:
            await act2.run()
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

Comment: `a2` and `a3` start to run at the same time - that alone is a proof that they run in parallel. Then `a1` starts before `a2` finished and so on. This wouldn't happen if all instances of A were sequential.

Comment: Try to play with concurrent execute on a single actor instance vs multiple - you will see the difference.